Flask and Jupyter, emulating calls to route functions from code cells
I have build a very very simple server to learn Flask and Jupiter and see How I made work them togheter:
`#%% ALL server logic
from flask import Flask,jsonify,request,make_response

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def nakedRoute():
    print('inside the teapot')
    return "I'm a teapot", 418

@app.route('/echo/', methods=['POST'])  
def serverAPI_ejemplo():
    try:
        if not request.is_json:
            return make_response(jsonify({"error": "I was expecting a JSON"}), 400)

        data = request.json['key'] + 1

        return jsonify({"key":data}), 200  # Código de estado 200 (OK)

    except Exception as e:
        return make_response(jsonify({"error": 33}), 500)
    

#%% Mount the server
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port=5000, debug=True)

In that sense, I can load all the funcionality in Jupiter within the first cell, and play with the code in real time
if I want to get the first route
# %% TEST naked router
with app.app_context():
    result= nakedRoute()
    print(result)

or If I want to test the 500 error on the second
# %% TEST /echo/ for error 500
with app.app_context():
    result= serverAPI_ejemplo()
    print(result)

Well..
except if I expect to add a Json to the CALL  :-(
# %% TEST /echo/ for a JSON
with app.app_context():
    my_JSON = {"key":33}
    #...???
    result= serverAPI_ejemplo()
    print(result)`

so far, I have not been able to complete the code to be able to call serverAPI_ejemplo, and get the JSON pas trough
EDIT:
I have been able to learn (thanks @Dmitri) hot to test the calls within a cell:
# %%   IT WORKS !!!!
if my_JSON == None:
    my_JSON = {"key":33}

with app.test_client() as c:
    headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"}
    response = c.post('/echo/', headers=headers, json=my_JSON)

    print(response.get_json())

    my_JSON = response.json

Is is not exactly what I was looking for, as I want to CALL the serverAPI_ejemplo function directly, if thats possible, and not make a post http call, that I belive it will go trought the TCP/IP stack, and not directly within Python execution enviroment
the reason: trying to learn and teach python

Flask is a framework for writing web applications and the route functions are intended to be accessed by making http requests to the associated endpoint using a web browser or a library like requests rather than being called directly. I can see little practical use for trying to combine flask with a Jupiter notebook in this way.

This question is similar to: Testing code that requires a Flask app or request context. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@Dmitry, thanks a lot for the post, I didn0t find before, it has help me, even it is not exactly what I was looking for, I explain in a response

If you want to test the functionality of serverAPI_ejemplo in isolation (without making an HTTP request), you could consider refactoring your code to separate the core functionality from the request handling.

@MingJie-MSFT , that's sad... refactoring to be able to test
